# How to pass an integer data from sqlite database to an integer variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

So I am new to iOS programming and I want to retrieve an integer data from my sqlite database and set to an integer variable, i dont really have a code to do it, I am really new to it. I have searched for any source code for it but all I can see is retrieving an nsstring, I cant use it cause I am wondering what if there is a big difference in retrieving a string and an integer. thanks!

Comment: Please make an attempt to do some research before posting a question like this. Start with the docs on sqlite.org or search for a tutorial.

Comment: ok rmaddy. thanks! I am very new to this, I am self studying, I dont have any background.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a result set in the statement `stmt` and the first column holds your int:

```
int column_0_value = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
```

See http://sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html for the full list of the SQLite C API.